# Call 2+ functions with Javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page.php and a func.php. I know that the request that I can do is with AJAX, but I don't know how do it. I searched here and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/php-function-call-using-javascript), but I don't understand how it works exactly.

This is my files:

page.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="func.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function hello(){
             $.ajax({ 
         url: 'func.php',
         data: {action: 'hello'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
        }
           });
        }

        function bye(){
              $.ajax({ 
              url: 'func.php',
              data: {action: 'bye'},
              type: 'post',
              success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            }
            });
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action method="post" name="form" id="form" action="javascript:hello();"  >
<button type="input">Hello</button>
</form>

<form action method="post" name="form" id="form" action="javascript:bye();"  >
<button type="input">Bye</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

func.php

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {

$action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'hello' : hello();break;
        case 'bye' : bye();break;
    }

function hello(){
    echo "Hello";
}

function bye(){
    echo "bye";
}
}
?>
```

The code is very simple, I only want that when a user click the button "hello" or "bye", the javascript call the function and print the result. This is a example of my real code, I know that if I want print "hello/bye" I don't need ajax or other file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Does the code work?

Comment: No, the code doesn't work. Don't print any, only recarge the page

Comment: `<form action="javascript:bye();"` is invalid, you should do `<button onclick="javascript:bye();"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up click handlers for your buttons. Give each button a unique ID and set up the lick listeners as in the example below.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hello").click(hello);
    $("#bye").click(bye);        
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="hello">Hello</button>
<button type="button" id="bye">Bye</button>
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LynTh/1/)**

Comment: This solve my problem to call the functions. But I need call the function on func.php from page.php. The content of alert has to come from func.php, not from the same file. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is what your code does :) You don't see the output because you are on page.php.

Comment: I know, but the original code have Selects, inserts and more php code, hence need call the functions on func.php. Thanks!

Comment: @GRQuest but that is what your code is doing! You are calling the functions in func.php

Comment: If you want func.php to return something, look up http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bye').bind('click', bye);
    $('#hello').bind('click', hello);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action method="post" name="form" id="form"  >
  <a id="hello">hello</a>
  <a id="bye">bye</a>
</form>
```