# Calling a php script using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to do what the title says following this example:

[How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/php-function-call-using-javascript)

However I can't get it to work.

Here is the javascript function:

```
  <script>
function errorInProyect(err){
    if (document.getElementById("projname").value == ""){
      document.getElementById("projname_status").innerHTML =  "El nombre del proyecto no puede estar vacio";
    }
    else{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'addproject.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {functionname: 'prueba'},
        success: function (obj) {
              document.getElementById("projname_status").innerHTML =  "El resultado fue " + obj.result;
            }
    });
    }
}
  </script>
```

And my addproject.php is:

```
<?php 
    $res = array();
    $res['result'] = "soy la prueba";
    json_encode($res);
?>
```

and I know that the function is being called because the message in case of the empty string is being printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you dint print anything? and where did you write this function prueba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't print the result of `json_encode`.

Change the code in `addproject.php` to:

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: According to the example I've read $res should be the result and it is what I get in obj.result. I should be able to see it if the code enters the function on success. Am I understanding the example wrong? Because in the example function names is simply used for a switch statement, to to actually call a function....

Comment: One more thing. In my defense the example in the link did not have the echo in the encode command, though......

Comment: you're right, the example seems wrong as well. glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function errorInProyect(err){
    if (document.getElementById("projname").value == ""){
      document.getElementById("projname_status").innerHTML =  "El nombre del proyecto no puede estar vacio";
    }
    else{
         $.post("addproject.php",{'functionname': 'prueba'},
                 function(data)
                   {
                      document.getElementById("projname_status").innerHTML =  "El resultado fue " + data.result;

                   },'json');

         }
}
  </script>
```

and you php page is

```
<?php 
    $res = array();
    $res['result'] = "soy la prueba";
    echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Comment: see the $.post() section. Its not copied and pasted. Made needed changes