# Wordpress tinyMCE custom button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I`m trying to insert custom button to my wordpress tinyMCE editor to call php function. I already inserted that button but i don't know how to call php function. The JavaScript code is here: 
Javascript:

```js
(function() {
  
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.PreButton', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
      ed.addCommand('preFormat', function() {
        ed.formatter.toggle('pre');
      });
      
      ed.addButton('pre', {
        title : 'IMG',
          text : 'IMG',
          onclick : function() { 
              ed.windowManager.open({
    title: 'Example plugin',
    body: [
     {type: 'textbox', name: 'img_url', label: 'IMG URL'},
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'img_info', label: 'Info'}
    ],
    onsubmit: function(e) {
     // Insert content when the window form is submitted
     ed.insertContent('<img src="' + e.data.img_url + '" alt="' + e.data.img_info + ' />');
    }
   });
          }
      });
      
    },
  });

  // Register plugin
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('preButton', tinymce.plugins.PreButton);
  
})();

PHP:
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package autoimage
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: autoimage
*/

function mcepre_add_buttons($plugin_array) {
  $plugin_array['preButton'] = plugins_url('mce-pre',__FILE__) . '/plugin.js';
  return $plugin_array;
}

function mcepre_register_buttons($buttons) {
  array_push( $buttons, 'pre');
  return $buttons;
}

function mcepre_buttons() {
  add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "mcepre_add_buttons");
  add_filter('mce_buttons', 'mcepre_register_buttons');
}
add_action( 'init', 'mcepre_buttons' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php function call using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/php-function-call-using-javascript)

Comment: This question essentially boils down to needing to call PHP from JavaScript, correct?

Comment: Almost. From wordpress plugin js