# call PHP function inside JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to call a php function inside a JS function, my php function uses an input as param and push the returned value in the :
index.html :

```
<input type="text" name="my_value">
<button type="button" name="confirm" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
```

my_script.JS:

```
    function validate() {
        var errors = [];
        //here I want to call check function using the input my_value
    }
```

test.php :

```
function check($my_value){
   //some long test on $my_value{
        return "valid";
    }else{
        return "not valid";
    }
}
```

How can I call it in my validate JS function?

Comment: you can use ajax to call php script in JS function

Comment: You can't (except via something like AJAX) by the time the client is running the JavaScript the server has done with the PHP, is putting its feet up and getting a lovely cuppa tea with a biscuit.

Comment: you can validate string length in js, then why using php ?

Comment: You can review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15758129/3077339 just apply valid path for your php file and its function.