# How to call a PHP function from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to call a specific php function using jQuery after my form is submitted, is there anyway to achieve that?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form id="frmAgregar" method="post">
    <input id="txtcant" class="centrado" type="number" value="1" required>
    <input class="btnSubmit btnResize" type="submit" value="Agregar +">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#frmAgregar").submit(function() {
    if ($("#txtcant").val() < 1 || $("#txtcant").val() == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        var popup = document.getElementById("popupAgregado");
        popup.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
        popup.setAttribute("class", "popupAgregado");       
        setTimeout(function () {popup.style.display='none'}, 1700);

        //HERE'S WHERE I NEED TO CALL THE PHP FUNCTION
    }   
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    function insertarDato() {
        $cant = $_POST["txtcant"];
        $query_insertarcontacto = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidotemp(cant) VALUES('$cant')", $cnbddelicomi) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you're redirecting the user, just use window.location?

Comment: Your header if for html not php

Comment: Not directly. JavaScript can invoke a PHP file with Ajax (or the `<form>` can submit to it), and that file can invoke the function.

Comment: yes I know, the thing is, I'm going to make php functions to insert and select data from a database. That's why I need to know how to call a specific function.

Comment: I also tried: $.ajax({ url: 'functionsphp.php' }); while putting the code in a external file.

Comment: @LeandroSS The ajax request can only request the file as a whole, not a specific function. So, `functionsphp.php` will have to invoke `IrA()` itself.

Comment: exactly I couldn't remember but try it <?PHP IrA(); ?> or this <?PHP echo IrA(); ?>

Comment: Do a POST AJAX call to functionsphp.php passing the value(s) as post data and in functionsphp read the value(s) using $VALUE = $_POST['X'];

Comment: You can't resend a header for a served page even through AJAX. So even if said PHP function is called, the page cannot, and will not, be refreshed. Headers can only be sent before any actual output.

Comment: I updated the PHP code to a mysql query, how can i call it to insert the data succesfully to the database? from jquery ofcourse...

Comment: @Terry not true.  The AJAX call is its own http request with its own http request headers and the AJAX headers have nothing to do with the containing page's http request and response.

Comment: You can try to use [php function call using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/php-function-call-using-javascript)

Comment: @Misunderstood I think you misunderstood me here. OPs original code involves invoking a refresh header when the Ajax call is made on the page triggering the Ajax call. You cannot remotely trigger a page refresh from AJAX unless you do it via JS. By issuing a new header via AJAX you are only declaring the header of the file called by AJAX, not the page that did the calling. But I can see that OP has changed his approach now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might need some help with a similar issue, I'm sharing how I solved this one...

**HTML**

```
<form id="frm-addcart" method="post">
  <input id="txt-quantity" class="text-center" type="number" value="1" required>
  <input id="btn-submit" class="submitted btn-resize" type="submit" value="Agregar +">
  <input type="hidden" id="checker-login" name="checker-login" value="isValid">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#btn-submit").on("click", function (event) {

  // DEFAULT ACTION OF THE EVENT WILL NOT BE TRIGGERED
  event.preventDefault();

  // GET THE VALUES FROM THE FORM
  var clickBtnValue = "btn-addcart";
  var checkerLogin = $("#checker-login").val();
  var quantity = $("#txt-quantity").val();

  // USE AJAX TO CALL THE PHP FUNCTION
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'php/functions.php',
    data : {
        "action" : clickBtnValue,
        "checkerLogin" : checkerLogin,
        "quantityAdded" : quantity      
    },
    success : function (data) {

        // data IS THE VALUE THAT THE PHP FUNCTION RETURNS THROUGH echo
        if (data == "valid") {
            window.location.href = "home.html";                     
        } else {                        
            alert("Something went wrong.");             
        }

    },
    error : function() {

        alert("An error has ocurred.");

    }
  });      

});
```

**php**

```
if (isset($_POST["action"]) == true) {
  switch ($_POST["action"]) {

    case "btn-addcart":
      insertData();
      break;

  }
}

function insertData() {

  // GET DATA FROM AJAX PARAMETERS
  $checkLogin = $_POST["checkerLogin"];
  &quantity = $_POST["quantityAdded"];

  // VALIDATE AND EXECUTE REST OF FUNCTION
  // AND IF EVERYTHING GOES OK
  echo "valid";
  exit();

}
```

And that's it! I'm calling a PHP function from jQuery.

Enjoy!