# List with elements from database in cloned jquery <tr>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a js script that inserts html elements into the page everytime a button is clicked. In one of those inputs(Select) i want to show a list of options retrieved from a database. I have the correct code for this but I have no idea how to combine them because i can not place PHP into JS.

My code:

```js
var rowCount = 0;
function add_product()
{
    var $table = $('table');

    var generateRow = function(indx){

        $table.append('<tr>\n\
                        <td></td>\
                      <td>\
                          <b>Aantal: </b><input style="width: 60px;" id="aantal" name="aantal_'+indx+'" type="number" min="0" required>\
                      </td>\
                      <td>\
                          <b>Product: </b><select name="products_'+indx+'" type="text" required>\n\
                                        </select>\
                      </td>\
                    </tr>');

    }
    generateRow(++rowCount);
}
```

```html
<?php

$productQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voorraad")

                                while ($productInfo = mysql_fetch_array($productQuery))
                                {
                                    $productID = $productInfo[0];
                                    $product = $productInfo[1];
                                    echo "<option value='$productID'>$product</option>";
                                }  
                            ?>
```

Comment: Will each product have the same set of options, or does each product have a different list of options depending upon the product?

Comment: You mean if every clone will have the same options? Yes they will. It is a list with products and they are all the same products. @beingalex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best method of doing what you're trying to achieve, but using the method you have started then it can be accomplished like this.

First you need to put the options string into a PHP variable
Then put that options string into a javascript variable.

This also assumes that your PHP and Javascript are all in the same document and that your PHP code is above your Javascript in the document.

```
<?php

$options = '';
$productQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voorraad")

                                while ($productInfo = mysql_fetch_array($productQuery))
                                {
                                    $productID = $productInfo[0];
                                    $product = $productInfo[1];
                                    $options .= "<option value='$productID'>$product</option>";
                                }  
                            ?>
```

---

```
var options = "<?php echo $options; ?>";
var rowCount = 0;
function add_product()
{
    var $table = $('table');

    var generateRow = function(indx){

        $table.append('<tr>\n\
                        <td></td>\
                      <td>\
                          <b>Aantal: </b><input style="width: 60px;" id="aantal" name="aantal_'+indx+'" type="number" min="0" required>\
                      </td>\
                      <td>\
                          <b>Product: </b><select name="products_'+indx+'" type="text" required>\n\
                          ' + options + ' </select>\
                      </td>\
                    </tr>');

    }
    generateRow(++rowCount);
}
```

Comment: I applied this code but the list still does not show any content @beingalex

Comment: The javascript variable options returns 0 when i alerted it @beingalex

Comment: I removed the $options += and put $options = because it didnt show anything in the list. Now it only shows the last element of the database. Do you have any options for this?

Comment: $options += should be $options .= (sorry! ). have updated.

Comment: .= concatenates a string

Comment: No problem. Sorry about the delayed reply - I was on my dinner. Heh

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your_functions_address.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {functionname: 'add', arguments: [1, 2]},

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                  if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                      yourVariable = obj.result;
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log(obj.error);
                  }
            }
});
```

From:

[How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/php-function-call-using-javascript)

Comment: I have never used that language and have a really hard time understanding it. Isn't there different way?