# php function inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am trying to execute a php function inside a javascript function. This javascript function is a form validation method which is called on through onclick method. This function validates the form fields and inserts the data into the mysql database.

I am calling this php function only when the form values are validated.
The problem is that even when the form entries are not validated, that is, even when i enter wrong data the function is being called.

However, if dont call the function here inside the script and i enter the php inside the body the validation works.

jobs.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(){
            var name= document.forms["Jform"]["name"];
            var email= document.forms["Jform"]["email"];
            var Experience= document.forms["Jform"]["experience"];
            var letters=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            var boolean=true;
            var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            if(name.value == ""){
                alert("Please enter your name");
                name.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }
            if((!email.value.match(mailformat)) || email.value==""){
                window.alert("Please enter proper email");
                email.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }
            if(Experience.value==""){
                window.alert("Please enter valid characters");
                email.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }

            if(boolean){
                <?php 
                    insertfunc();
                ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This is my code.

To rephrase, i want the php function to execute only when the form values are validated.

Could someone please help

Comment: Doesn't work that way. You need to call your php function via an AJAX call.

Comment: could please tell me how i am supposed to do that

Comment: nosense as written here. please read first about server-side and client-side language. Both can't be mixed... There are plenty of books about that, and of course online resource. ; voting for closing post as the missing knowledge is too broad for a post answer

Comment: @Dhirish What does insertfunc() do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript)

Comment: @JakubJudas it inserts data into the db

Comment: is there a possible way that i could send the boolean value again back to the same page?

Comment: @Dhirish In that case, the easiest way would be to create another php script (let's call it insert.php) and then send the data to that script using ajax - if you have jQuery include, you can use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ (example: $.post( "insert.php", { name: name, email:email } );

Comment: @Dhirish The practical problem with your original code is that PHP is eecuted on the server and then the response is sent to the user's browser, where javascript is executed. These two cannot cooperate any more - in fact, at the time of javascript execution, the PHP script has already finished and been terminated so it is no longer even running.

Comment: OK @JakubJudas thank you!

Comment: Hi @JakubJudas i tried using window.location.replace("jobs.php?boolean=true");
   return false;

Comment: but this time only empty values are being stored inside the db

Comment: @Dhirish If that is the only thing you changed, then it cannot work. There is no check in PHP for the value boolean. I think you still do not undertand the concept properly. You absolutely need to separate PHP and javascript completely. PHP will never see javascript variables. It might actually help you if you force yourself not to write javascript code and php code in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try this but don't assume the exact code will work, you have to debug it as per your need -

Assuming your php response will be JSON format with 200 status code. 
You jobs.php file's JS code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        // Your JS Ajax function to call insertfunc.php where your php code resides
        function insertData() {
            var nameValue = document.forms["Jform"]["name"];
            var emailValue = document.forms["Jform"]["email"];
            var experienceValue = document.forms["Jform"]["experience"];

            $.ajax({
                url: "<your-path-to>/insertfunc.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    name: nameValue, // Get name value as $_REQUEST["name"] in PHP
                    email: emailValue,
                    experience: experienceValue,
                },
                success: function(result) {

                    if(result.code == 200) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function validate(){
            var name= document.forms["Jform"]["name"];
            var email= document.forms["Jform"]["email"];
            var Experience= document.forms["Jform"]["experience"];
            var letters=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            var boolean=true;
            var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
            if(name.value == ""){
                alert("Please enter your name");
                name.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }
            if((!email.value.match(mailformat)) || email.value==""){
                window.alert("Please enter proper email");
                email.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }
            if(Experience.value==""){
                window.alert("Please enter valid characters");
                email.focus();
                boolean=false;
                return false;
            }

            if(boolean){
                // Call your Ajax function here
                insertData();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Keep your insertfunc.php where your php insert code resides.
Eg -

```
<?php 
    $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
    //...
    // Your php insert functionality
?>
```