# Calling woocommerce (php) function from custom javascript variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to have a custom variable in google tag manager that identifies if a page is a product page, for that i want to use Woocommerce is_product() function and pass it to GTM/GA as a custom dimension.

I already tried the solution seen here : [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript) like so:

```
function() {
    return <?php is_product(); ?>
}
```

But with no success since it always return "Undefined".

I'm a little inexperienced in javascript and php so I'm afraid that I'm missing something that is not calling properly is_product() or is_product() not returning what its supposed to return.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can only do it through Ajax… But ajax is advanced, sensible and can be very complex.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will need to find another way then!