# How to get image display in html when you get path from php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    $path=$row['path'];
?>
<img src="<?php$path?>" alt="thing" >
```

please tell if there is any other way , this is not working

Comment: PHP is a server sided language. In order to *properly* interact with it, you'll have to use JavaScript to make an XHR call, retrieve this path, and pass it into the image's src attribute. Mingling PHP and HTML as you have done is not a good practice

Comment: but i don't know java script. can you share syntax. it'll really help

Comment: Please see this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript you're going to have to do a fair bit of research because something like this uses 3 languages to do in a modern way

Comment: `<?php$path?>` You need to `echo $path`, just `$path` will do nothing. `<?php echo $path ?>`

Comment: no , not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a space here :

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>" alt="thing" >
```

Comment: can you explain what return $row['path'] ?

Comment: this code is working fine because when i output (echo $path) it gives me correct path in php

Comment: im fetching path from database

Comment: In that case I think your $row['path'] might not be good can you show us an example of what is stored in $row['path'] ?

Comment: also im using php 7.3.12 ver , is this syntax valid for it maybe

Comment: First you should use relative path instead of absolute like `\hostel-im\hostel1\h3.jpg`, then can you reach the image by just pasting the path in your browser ?

Comment: yeeesssssssssssssssssssss!!!    hostel-im\hostel1\h3.jpg (this worked) thankyou so much !!

Comment: Use forward slashes in URLs.