# PHP, mySQL, quiz with randomized questions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to build quiz which should work according to the following sequence:

1. Welcome screen with START button
2. after clicking START one question from the database (mySQL) is drawn and displayed on the screen (only one question is visible for user),
3. User have to choose option A or B
4. after clicking A or B (answer should be written to the array), then next question is drawn from the database (the question number cannot be repeated)
5. User have to choose option A or B

etc.. etc... until user answers for 10 random questions

after 10 answers I want SELECT from database gratulations referring to all the answers (WHERE IN)

index.php (main file):

```html
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<div> 
  Some informations - only text 
</div>
<div class ="quiz" id="quiz">

    <?php
        include 'quiz.php';
    ?>

</div>
```

quiz.php:

```html
<?php
    include 'draw-questions.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $aResult = array();

    if (isset($_POST['start-quiz'])) { $option = "start"; }

    if( isset($_POST['next-question_a']) ) { $option = "next"; }
    if( isset($_POST['next-question_b']) ) { $option = "next"; }

    switch ($option){

        case 'start':
                $index = 0;
                $draw_q_ID = DrawQuestion();
                $q_ID = $draw_q_ID[$index];
                $drawn_question = PickQuestion($q_ID);
                $question = explode(",", $drawn_question);
                RunQuiz();
                break;
        case 'next':
                $index++;
                $q_ID = $draw_q_ID[$index];
                $drawn_question = PickQuestion($q_ID);
                $question = explode(",", $drawn_question);
                RunQuiz();
                break;
        default:
                echo"
                    <div class='quiz-intro'>
                        welcome text
                    </div>
                    <form method='POST' action='' >
                    <input type='submit' id='start-quiz' name='start-quiz' value='START'>
                    </form>        
                ";
                break;

    }

  function RunQuiz(){

        ?>
        <script>
            const myNode2 = document.getElementById("quiz");
            while (myNode2.firstChild) {
                myNode2.removeChild(myNode2.lastChild);
            }
        </script>

        <?php

        global $question;
        
             echo "
                <div class='container' id='quiz-form'>
                    <div class='row'>
                         <div class='col-md-5' id='opcja_A' value='$question[0]'>
                             <input type='submit' id='next-question_a' name='next-question' value='$question[0]' style='color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0)'> 
                             <img src='../img_d/$question[1]' style='width:80%; padding: 20px 0'>
                             <h2>$question[0]</h2>
                         </div>
                         <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <img src='../img_d/vs.png' style='width:40%; padding-top:10rem'>
                         </div>
                         <div class='col-md-5' id='opcja_B' value='$question[2]''>
                             <input type='submit' id='next-question_b' name='next-question' value='$question[2]' style='color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0)'> 
                             <img src='../img_d/$question[3]' style='width:80%; padding: 20px 0'>
                             <h2>$question[2]</h2>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
             ";
```

draw-questions.php:

```html
<?php

    function DrawQuestion(){
        $q_ID = array();

        while(sizeof($q_ID)<=30) {
            $number = str_pad(rand(1, 57), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            if (!in_array($number, $q_ID)) {
                array_push($q_ID, $number);
            }
        }

        return $q_ID;
    }



    function PickQuestion($q_ID){

        require '../config/db_connection.php';

        $quiz = "SELECT * FROM `quiz` WHERE `d_id` = '$q_ID'";

        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($quiz);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row_quiz = $stmt->fetch()) {

            $question_a = $row_quiz['d_a'];
            $question_a_image = $row_quiz['d_a_image'];
            $question_b = $row_quiz['d_b'];
            $question_b_image = $row_quiz['d_b_image'];
        }

        $result = $question_a.','.$question_a_image.','.$question_b.','.$question_b_image;
        return $result;
    }
```

I think about it and try to solve my problem for a long time. All the time I have a problem with writing the answers to the array and drawing another question. Using  I always lose the answers and number of questions I already have the answer. Of course I can draw 10 questions at once, but the problem is to display them one at a time and collect answers somewhere.

Any suggestions, tips how should I approach this? How can I store answer after clicking answer and go to next question without loosing questions id's and answers?
I also tried JS and jQuery [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript) but with no results

Comment: Store/Retrieve your answer array in a session. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: 1) either you can store user answers in database when user select among A or B 
......

2) or you can store data in session.