# How to create random numbers at set time interval in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, procedure

I want to insert random numbers between 23 and 31 at every 5 seconds in a Mysql table.

I know that I have to use [RAND()](https://database.guide/mysql-rand-function-generate-a-random-number-in-mysql/) function. But i don't know how to use it for inserting random numbers at set time interval.

Comment: what does `select version()` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event scheduler for this:

```
create table foo (id int primary key auto_increment, value int);
create event insert_random_value_every_5_sec on schedule every 5 second do insert into foo (value) select floor(23+rand()*9) as value;
```

If the event scheduler is disabled, you will need to enable it:

```
set global event_scheduler=on;
```

You can specify start and or end times for the event in the create event statement or later in alter event.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you random numbers `FLOOR(RAND()*(31-23+1))+23`  And this will give you data in every 5 second date `MOD(SECOND(curdate()) ,5)=0`. You can use this sql -

```
SELECT
FLOOR(RAND()*(31-23+1))+23
FROM table
WHERE MOD(SECOND(curdate()) ,5)=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do i use it with insert into syntax ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table(rand_col) SELECT
FLOOR(RAND()*(31-23+1))+23 rand_col
FROM table
WHERE MOD(SECOND(curdate()) ,5)=0 `

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can use PHP file and using script `timeInterval` with AJAX to insert the random value to the database. I will tell you step by step but without code.

Steps:

1. create PHP function to connect your database (you can Googling with keysearch mysqli_connect)
2. create PHP function to handle your AJAX request and save it in database (keysearch: mysqli_query)
3. create script function (ex: named ajax_query) to send AJAX request with RAND function to generate random number as you wish. (You can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript))
4. create script interval function to call function "ajax_query"

PS: don't forget to include/use jQuery library in your file

Comment: I would recommend to use PDO instead of mysqli when connecting to database using PHP. It is much easier and better. Here is a good tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo