# my php code does not run in the html script tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi I write a php file that contains two methods :

**1)**

```
function restart(){ echo('restart') };
```

**2)**

```
function shutdown(){echo ('shutdown')};
```

then I include the **index.php** file to the **foo.php** and when I want to call index.php **methods** in an **eventHandler** in foo.php it doesn't work like this:

```
    <?php
include ('index.php');

?>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <button id='res'>restart</button>
    <button id='sht'>shutdown</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('res').addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('restarted');
            <?php

           restart();
           ?>
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

output: **nothing and no errors**

---

and when I **remove** the php code **inside the eventHandler** it works! like this:

---

```
  <?php
    include ('index.php');

?>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <button id='res'>restart</button>
    <button id='sht'>shutdown</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('res').addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log('restarted');
           
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

output: **restarted**

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?**

Comment: You need a semicolon after the `echo` statements - at the moment it's outside the function (after the `}`).

Comment: Turn on error logging to the screen or to a file and see what error(s) PHP is throwing.

Comment: You can using ajax request to server instead of call php code in javascript code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is being run when the file is 'rendered', so the function call to `restart`, even though it is within the JavaScript event listener, is being run on render. If you check the source (after fixing the missing semicolon), it should show `restart` in place of the PHP code.

You cannot call PHP code within JavaScript, as JavaScript is client side and PHP is server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , so why the **console.log("restarted")** doesnt work?!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use console.log in echo statement as well.. follow the below example. Assuming your index.php file code is already been added on top to explain you better.

```html
<?php 

function restart(){ echo (" console.log('restarted')"); }

function shutdown(){echo (" console.log('shutdown')"); }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <button id='res'>restart</button>
    <button id='sht'>shutdown</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('res').addEventListener('click',function(){
           //console.log('restarted');
            <?php
           restart();
           ?>
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer is probably missing the point (that the OP expects the php restart function to be called when clicking the button in the web) and is indirectly pointing out that the output of the php function, when embedded in a script tag, must be valid js. But no php function should be called like that, the problem/misunderstanding is larger than that. As written, the question’s code is missing an xhr request.

Comment: The question is simple the user needs to call php function based on button click , so I did that according. If you have a time to test than this code does fulfill the requirement. Let the actual user respond as what he says about this.

Comment: That is not true, please consider the “restart” function actually doing something (e.g. replace it with `exit;`) and when it would do it - The php function is called on render. Please see the duplicate question I’ve linked to.

Comment: Its not, just remove console.log('restarted') from JavaScript code and then test, when you will click the restart button than only that function will be called, check in console.

Comment: I have commented console.log from JavaScript, now test.