# Dynamically generating data list textbox from a database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a project that requires text boxes to be dynamically generated. the problem that I am running into is these text boxes must also have a datalist generated by a database. these tasks on their own are fairly easy but to accomplish both I have to call a php function within my javascript. does anyone know how to call a php function with javascript?

Comment: generally people use Ajax to send a request from the client to a PHP script but from the sounds of this you could output the db results as json and let javascript process them as you see fit to produce the datalists and textfields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call PHP functions by JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript)